# Selecting large number of nodes in dynatree is slow

Tags: jquery-plugins, dynatree

I am using dynatree for loading geographical locations in a hierarchical fashion. I have to programmatically select large number of nodes depending on the response from web service. It takes long time to render it on the GUI. IN FF, It takes atleast 3 mins, and in IE 8, I get slow script error. I use the following code to select the nodes in a loop.

```
tree.getNodeByKey(data).select()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server could set the `select` attibutes of the nodes when sending them to the client, this would be more efficient, of course.

If that is not an option, you may consider another pattern, assuming you have an array of keys that should be selected:

Use `tree.visit()` to iterate over all nodes, and call `node.select()`, if `node.data.id` is a member of the array.

Comment: i used the first option. It is better now. Thanks